How to change the color scheme in an Angular app without using any additional libraries
How can I change the entire color scheme of an angular app on click of a button without using any other UI library.
Basically what I want to do is - I have two files dark.scss and light.scss. Both contains variables such as the below one but with the different values.
:root{
    --body-bg:#fff;   
    --frn-bg-color:#fff;
    --input-border-color:#787878;
    //...
}

Which is then called in the styles.scss file using @require './theme/dark.scss';. But this is very static and cannot change to @require './theme/light.scss'; without rebuilding the app.
So what can I do to switch the theme files and apply all the color scheme without rebuilding the app.

Seems like what you are looking for is a tutorial on Angular plain scss light and dark mode toggle. This one looks pretty good: https://dev.to/pahanperera/implement-light-dark-mode-in-angular-42ff. It uses global CSS variables, SCSS mixins and applies a class to the document body depending on which colour scheme you have selected at runtime.

Instead of using :root use body.light and body.dark as selector for setting the variables. You can then via JS change the document.body.classList to .add or .remove the one you need.
Example:
.light {
    --body-bg:#fff;   
    --frn-bg-color:#fff;
    --input-border-color:#787878;
    //...
}

then
document.body.classList
  // remove both
  .remove('light', 'dark')
  // add the desired one
  .add('light');

